# Information about Goddess Ugrachanda

Tags: identification-request, goddess

I Recently I have heard about goddess Ugrachanda and I want to know this incarnation of goddess Parvati. But what is information about this goddess? Is any mention about her in Puranas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sri chandika took diffrent forms to slay mahishasura in diffrent kalpas one such is ugrachandaAs per Kalika Purana, Mahishasur was a Shivansh or one of the Maruts born as daitya... Shiva gave birth to two Shivansh one Dharma and second Adharma. Adharma incarnated three times In 2nd Manvantar he was a buffalo demon he was son of Rambha... at this Vishnu Incarnated as Singh or Narsingha. Devi was ashta dash mahalaksmi or Chandi. In 5th Manvantra adharma incarnated again as king of tribesman who eventually was killed by Ugra Chandika or katyani. At last in present manvantra he incarnated as king Mysore devi incarnated as chamundeshwari Bhadrakali... Mahishasur asked devi to get salvation. She said at the climax of present Kalyug you will incarnate as machine incarnation (Rahuvesh Mahishasur) I will take the form of Kaalika and slew you and provide you mukti....The eighteen armed form named Ugrachanda manifested with one crore Yoginis. Her hair was matted and decked with three crowns featuring the crescent. She wore a serpent as her garland and also a garland of gold. The goddess who had protruding teeth held in her right hands a trident, a sword, a conch, a discus, an arrow, a spear, a thunderbolt and a rod. In her left hands, she had two varieties of shields, a bow, a noose, a goad, a bell, an axe and a club. In her lower most right and left hands she held a mace and a drinking bowl. On her head she wore a garland of human heads. Her complexion resembles that of crushed collyrium and in a terrible form with a huge body, red eyes and eighteen arms, she rides on a lion.

Source: Quora

On further research I found this article on wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navadurga

According to traditions and Hindu scriptures Navadurga has different forms. The list of Navadurga in 50th Chapter of Agni Purana is given below.

> Rudrachanda
> Prachanda
> Chandogra
> Chandanayika
> Chanda
> Chandavati
> Chandarupa
> Atichandika
> Ugrachanda

> Ugracaṇḍā (उग्रचण्डा):—Name of one of the goddesses to be worshipped during Āvaraṇapūjā (“Worship of the Circuit of Goddesses”), according to the Durgāpūjātattva (“The truth concerning Durgā’s ritual”). They should be worshipped with either the five upācāras or perfume and flowers.

Her mantra is as follows:

ह्रीं ओं उग्रचण्डायै नमः
hrīṃ oṃ ugracaṇḍāyai namaḥ

Source: Brill: Śaivism and the Tantric Traditions (shaktism)
Ugracaṇḍā (उग्रचण्डा) refers to one of the Navadurgā (“nine Durgās”), whose worship formed a part of the Navarātra Tantric ritual (an autumnal festival of the warrior goddess Caṇḍikā).—On Mahāṣṭamī is the worship of the Nine Durgās (e.g., Ugracaṇḍā), the eight mothers, the sixty-four Yoginīs, purification of the gross elements, installation of mantras on the body; [...] Goddess is believed to morph into a more uncontrollable presence requiring constant placation.—Various 8th century sources refer to rituals such as the worship of Ugracaṇḍā, for example: Devīpurāṇa, Kālikāpurāṇa, Kṛtyakalpataru, Durgābhaktitaraṅgiṇī, Durgāpūjātattva, Durgāpūjāviveka,